# Manipulating a List of String in Java

Tags: java, list

please, I'm having the code shown below:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add("foo");
    System.out.println("\nThis is list 1 : " +list1); //foo

    List<String> list2 = list1;
    System.out.println("\nThis is list 1 : " +list1); // foo
    System.out.println("\nThis is list 2 : " +list2); // foo

    List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<>(list2);
    System.out.println("\nThis is list 3 : " +list3); // foo
    list1.clear();
    System.out.println("\nThis is list 1 : " +list1); // []
    list2.add("bar");
    list3.add("baz");

    System.out.println("\nThis is list 1 : " +list1); // bar
    System.out.println("\nThis is list 2 : " +list2); // bar
    System.out.println("\nThis is list 3 : " +list3); // [foo, baz]

}
```

output:

```
**list 1 : [bar], list2 : [bar], list3 : [foo, baz]**
```

My question is how did **list1** get the value **bar**? because I was thinking it was supposed to be empty at the time. And also, I was thinking that **list2** is going to have the values **[foo, bar]** at this time. Please what is the logic behind this?

Comment: Because you have one list, `List<String> list2 = list1;` does not make a new `List`. Change it to `List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>(list1);` for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## 1 `ArrayList`, 2 references

Understand that `List<String> list1` and `List<String> list2` do *not* hold a list. They hold a [*reference*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(computer_science)) (pointer) to a list.

Your line:

```
List<String> list2 = list1;
```

…copies the contents of `list1` (a reference) to `list2`. You copied the reference (basically a memory address number), not the list.

Your variable `list2` points to the same `ArrayList` object as `list1`. You have 2 *references* but only 1 *list*. So making a change through either reference will be visible through both.

[image: diagram showing two reference variables both pointing to the same ArrayList object]

### Make a copy

As [commented by Elliott Frisch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68449330/manipulating-a-list-of-string-in-java/68449352#comment120971050_68449330), if you want a copy of a list, [pass to the constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.Collection)).

```
List< String > list2 = new ArrayList<>( list1 ) ;  // Make copy of one list by passing to constructor of another.
```

[image: diagrams of two references pointing to two different list objects]

This is a *shallow* copy, meaning we are copying the references into a new list the original objects to which the references point are *not* copied. So the *references* are being copied, not the *referents*.

```java
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add("foo");
System.out.println("list1: " + list1 );          // foo

List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>( list1 ) ;  // foo
list1.clear();                                   // empty 
list2.add( "bar" );                              // foo, bar
System.out.println( "list1: " +list1 );          // empty
System.out.println( "list2: " +list2 );          // foo, bar
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/N4DdM4).

```
list1: [foo]
list1: []
list2: [foo, bar]
```

### Immutable copy

Or, for an immutable copy, use [`List.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#copyOf(java.util.Collection)). If not already immutable, you get a duplicate list.

```
List< String > list2 = List.copyOf( list1 ) ;  // Creating an immutable copy of the first list, *if* that list is not already immutable.
```

If a mutable list underlies the immutable list such as with [`Collections.unmodifiableList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)), you can combine these two techniques to ensure a separate fresh immutable list is produced.

```
List<String> list2 = List.copyOf( new ArrayList<>( list1 ) ) ;
```

Comment: Oh, I got it, thank you so much for the explanation, sir

Answer (score 1):

The following statement lets `list2` refer to the same list as `list1`

`List<String> list2 = list1;`

However,`list3` uses another list to initialize itself.

`List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<>(list2);`

I think that you should know about the difference between shallow and deep copy...